# Get all usages of a TypeDeclerationSyntax in Incremental Source Generator

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I have a generic class and i need to access all generic usages of that class using incremental source generators.

My class is like:

```
public class User<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

and in somewhere in code, i use it like:

```
User<bool> userWithBool = new();
```

and

```
User<SomeOtherClass> userWithSomeOtherClass = new();
```

I need to get that `bool` and `SomeOtherClass`. How can i do that? I can't find any info on google about this.

Comment: The usage of `User<T>` won't be a `TypeDeclarationSyntax`, it'll be a `GenericNameSyntax` found within a `VariableDeclarationSyntax`. Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: I get all the GenericNameSyntax'es and then, I use them when I need them. Thank you for your reply. I found the answer three-four days ago by ditching the api of incremental generators.